# How to simply pass fill parameters with a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, parameters

I have created a list of dict that handle all the needed data. I want to pass them into a function.

This function await multiple parameters. I want to write the parameters_key and their corresponding values on a dictionary to separate data and functionality.

How can I make my dict_key correspond to param_key to not rewrite the keys on the function call ?

```
param_dict_list = [
    {"a":"az","b":"dsf","c":"5144"},
    {"a":"fsg","b":"tyr","c":"786"},
    {"a":"aeyrjz","b":"ertr","c":"45"},
    {"a":"jk","b":"ui","c":"2545"},
]

def my_func(a, b, c):
    print(a,b,c)
```

**ACTUAL**

```
for d in param_dict_list:
    my_func(a=d["a"], b=d["b"], c=d["c"])
```

**WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR**

```
for d in param_dict_list:
    my_func(kwargs=d) #it doesn't work, I don't know how to write it properly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
for params in param_dict_list:
    my_func(**params)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists. Here is a relevant snippet from the documentation:

> [...] dictionaries can deliver keyword arguments with the **-operator:
>
> ```py
> >>> def parrot(voltage, state='a stiff', action='voom'):
> ...     print("-- This parrot wouldn't", action, end=' ')
> ...     print("if you put", voltage, "volts through it.", end=' ')
> ...     print("E's", state, "!")
> ...
> >>> d = {"voltage": "four million", "state": "bleedin' demised",  "action": "VOOM"}
> >>> parrot(**d)
> -- This parrot wouldn't VOOM if you put four million volts through it. E's bleedin' demised !
> ```